# Button on bottom of page in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The problem is:

I need to place button #2 on bottom of the page.

I search here, on google, I try do this with `position absolute/relative` and `bottom:0; height:100%` and many other variants - but it does not work.

The idea is - the first and second buttons must be in visible area. We can scroll only in `some_div`.

How to do this?

Thanks!

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <h3>Test</h3>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"> 1</button>
   
    <div id="some_div" style="min-height:100%; height:100%; overflow-y: auto;">
        Many-many text. We can scroll in it.
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block push-to-bottom"> 2</button>

  </div>


  <div class="col-md-2">.col-md-2</div>
  <div class="col-md-2">.col-md-2</div>
  <div class="col-md-2">.col-md-2</div>
  <div class="col-md-2">.col-md-2</div>
  <div class="col-md-2">.col-md-2</div>
</div>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  </body>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
button.push-to-bottom
{
   position:fixed;
   bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: It fills all columns, but need only one

Comment: move the button out of the col div and into the row div?

Comment: buttons #1 and #2 must be in col div

Comment: What is the purpose of this code? Please explain it.

Comment: @CarolMcKay: yes. Why do you use `position` and `bottom` rules? In other words, how can this answer be useful to other users?